# express.Router() is undefined after converting to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript, mean-stack

I am converting my express nodejs project from JS to TypeScript. I renamed the file extension, **changed var to import for "require()"**, however there is one thing that is working and is undefined, express.Router().

```
import express = require('express');
var router = express.Router(); // Undefined
import mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

What should I do to resolve it?!

Comment: You shouldn't have to do any renaming, just install the typescript definitions for express.

Comment: I am using Webstorm IDE since I am learning so IDE makes things a bit easier. Where would I put the typescript definitions?

Comment: import {express } from 'path to express module'

Answer (score 0):

First, in you project directory, you need to install typings

```
npm install -g typings
```

Then, install the typing destination for expressJS

```
typings install express --ambient --save
```

This will create a typings.json and should fix your problem